# Faux Columns Mysteriously Stopped Working When Windowed

Tags: html, css

I've been working on styling my integrated news system (CuteNews) and all of a sudden my Faux columns have stopped. I hit undo quite a few times, but it appears this broke some time ago and it went un-noticed by me. My code has not changed for my faux columns. Would like if someone could take a look at my code/site and see what may be causing the problem here...

EDIT: This only appears to happen when my resolution shrinks, can anybody elaborate?

My website is [DBZ Final Cut](http://dbzfinalcut.com)

Thanks for any help!

The HTML follows, relating to just my columns:

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="content">
    <img class="contentHead" src="images/general/site/content.png" alt="Content">
    <?php
  $number = "5";
  include("news/show_news.php");
?>
    </div>
    <!--End Content-->
    <!--Start Side Content-->
    <div class="sideContent">
        <img src="images/general/site/cotw.png">
        <img src="images/general/site/decklist.png">
        <img src="images/general/site/events.png">
        <img src="images/general/site/rules.png">
        <span>Top Articles</span>
    </div>
    <!--End Side Content-->
```

The CSS follows, relating to just my columns:

```
.contentWrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 21.35%;
    width: 57.29%;
    background: grey;
    margin-top: .02%;
    background: url("../images/general/site/faux.png") repeat-y;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #bfbfc6;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.content > p {
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 1%;
    padding-top: 0;
    font-size: .9vw;
}
.contentHead {
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 1%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sideContent {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 30%;
    background: grey;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: #888888;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: .9vw;
    padding-top: 1%;
}
.sideContent > p {
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 7%;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting the background-size to contain. Works perfectly now.